# How to get time passed since video started with YouTube iframe api?

Tags: jquery, youtube-api

I want to get time passed (in percent) since video started in using YouTube iframe api.

I've done this so far:

```
$(".timeInPercent").click(function() {

var playerTotalTime = player.getDuration();
var playerCurrentTime = Math.round(player.getCurrentTime());

var playerTimeDifference = playerTotalTime / playerCurrentTime;
var playerTimePercent = playerTimeDifference * 100;

progress(playerTimePercent, $('#progressBar'));
});
```

I need this for a custom progression bar I made. I just need to update this `progress(playerTimePercent, $('#progressBar'));` with time passed in percent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need playerCurrentTime / playerTotalTime, rather than the other way around. Then multiply by 100 to get percentage, as you're doing.